# zip artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifact

I would like to get a zip file with artifacts.
The archiveArtifacts directive in Jenkinsfile will save each artifact,
but when you download it you will get a zip files with original paths in it.
Is it possible to avoid original paths with a directive or am I obliged to
run a script that callects all artifacts in one single folder in the workspace and zip the folder then?

Comment: Could you please explain me with the some examples because it is still unclear to me :)

Comment: By using archiveArtifacts I will get for example the folllowing artifacts:
dir1/dir2/file1.exe
dir3/dir4/dir5/file2.bin

and if I download them from the Jenkins web interface I will get an archive.zip with
the same dir structure.

INstead I would like to get a zip file with:
fie1.exe
file2.bin

without original paths

Comment: Okay now it is reproducible. I will be back with the solution sir 

Comment: The solution is rather easy, you should move your atrifacts to `$WORKSPACE` before archiving them.Please remember to take care of the cases where there are files with the same name (e.g. `folder_1/file.txt` and `folder_2/file.txt`) and others, which is probably why the pipeline step doesn't do it natively.

Comment: Thanks @MaratC : your suggestion is really helpful.  I was wondering if there could be an option to the archiveArtifacts. And yes, name clash is what the default behavior avoids.